# No quotation mark in a book?

Tags: technical, quotation-marks, reading

So I just bought this book 'Requiem for a dream' and I just "found out" that there is no quotation mark in the book in a conversation. So it's up to me to tell when the converstation started by who! Anyone knows what this is. A traditional novel style of something?! How can I do some read with this?

[image: Snapshot of a page]

Comment: Artistic license? Try Ulysses or, worse, Finnegan's Wake.

Comment: Or Faulkner (*The Sound and the Fury*), William Styron (*Lie Down In Darkness*), or any of the rest who used interior monologue, stream-of-consciousness, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The novel is about heroin and heroin addiction I think.  I would assume the no quotes style is a literary device intended to invoke the author's vision of the helter skelter stream of consciousness nature of drug addiction.

Look at something like Howl by Ginsberg.  You don't get the courtesy of a period/full stop for 260 lines.

It's a style thing I think you will need to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a wholly uncommon style, especially where there is an emphasis on the rhythm of the spoken language, which would be broken by the usual punctuation and "he said/she said" phrases.

It can be hard to untangle the contributions from different speakers when it's formatted like this, but try to interpret it as the transcript of a real conversation, and see how it *sounds* in your head.